# How to use a global variable in Vitest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, vitest

I am writing a unit test in Vue, Vitest. Now I have a config object in a file in my public folder. This is being used as env variables. Not ideal, but it's a legacy project we're migrating. One step at a time.

I am able to call the config variable from anywhere in my code. It is added as a script tag in my index.html, and included in my tsconfig.json file.

When I run my uni test however, it says that config is not defined.

I tried some stuff out, including the populateGlobal function like this:

```
populateGlobal(global, {config})
```

And just defining it in my setup file like this:

```
const config = {}
```

I am using happy-dom and set globals to true like this:

```
test: {
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        globals: true,
        mockReset: true,
        restoreMocks: true,
        clearMocks: true,
        setupFiles: ['vitest.setup.ts']
    }
```

But that doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to make it work with my tests?

Comment: Had a similar issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77992893/5233188, in my case I could just set the global via `global.window`, so I assume this should work in other cases too...